# How can I display @wire iteration data in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire

I am training in LWC, and am attempting to display wired data in an iteration 'template' element.

The data shows up in my browser console, and I can also get a 'test' string to show up for each of the records, but the actual fields pulled are not displayed.

[image]

Here is my code:

**ApexHoursDevApp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:firstLwcApd/>
</aura:application>
```

**firstLwcApd.html**

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-var-m-around_large">
        <h1>Welcome to the world of LWC!</h1>
        <lightning-input label="Type Here" required value={inputText} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input> 
        <p>
            {greeting} {inputText}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-var-m-around_large">
        <template for:each={data} for:item="contact">
            <p key={contact.id}>
                {contact.id} test
            </p>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

**firsLwcApd.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ApexHoursDemoClass.getContactList';

export default class FirstLwcApd extends LightningElement {
    greeting = 'Welcome to Apex Hours';
    inputText = 'Type Here';
    @api message = 'This is a simple message';
    data;
    error;

    handleChange(event){
        this.inputText = event.target.value;
        window.console.log(' event.target', event.target);
    }

    //Get a class
    //Create an aura enabled apex method
    //Import aura enabled apex method

    @wire(getContactList)
    wiredData ({error, data}) {
        if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.result = undefined;
            window.console.log(' this.error: ', this.error);
        } else if (data) {
            window.console.log( 'data: ', data);
            this.error = undefined;
            this.data = data;
            window.console.log( 'this.data: ', this.data );
        }
    }
}
```

**ApexHoursDemoClass.cls**

```
public with sharing class ApexHoursDemoClass {
    public ApexHoursDemoClass() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContactList(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 20];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. Make sure you use correct variable names on your front end HTML markup.

The below should fix it

```
<template for:each={data} for:item="contact">
        <p key={contact.Id}>
            {contact.Id} test
        </p>
    </template>
```

Note instead of contact.id, I am using **contact.Id**

Comment: Thanks Mohith! This resolved the issue.

Interesting how it worked lowercase for 'key={contact.id}', but not for the '{contact.id' in between the <p></p>.